# JPA EntityManager does not persist

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have a problem with JPA and persisting data in to the database. 
I have the following class

```
public class Grabber {

     private EntityManagerFactory emfactory;
     private EntityManager entitymanager;

     public EntityManager getManager(){
         emfactory =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "DSLTestV4" );
         entitymanager = emfactory.
                createEntityManager( );
         entitymanager.getTransaction( ).begin( );
         return entitymanager;

    }

     public void Close(){
        entitymanager.getTransaction().commit();
        entitymanager.close();
        emfactory.close();
    }

}
```

And the following wich extends the grabber

```
public class TestfixtureGrabber extends Grabber{

    public List<Testfixture> getAll(){

        EntityManager manager = getManager();
        List<Testfixture> result = manager.createNamedQuery("Testfixture.findAll").getResultList();
        Close();
        return result;      
    }

    public Testfixture getById(int id){
        EntityManager manager = getManager();
        TypedQuery<Testfixture> query = manager.createQuery("SELECT w FROM User w WHERE w.user=" +id ,Testfixture.class);

        Testfixture result = query.getSingleResult();
        Close();
        return result;
    }

    @Transactional
    public int SaveTestfixture(Testfixture t){
        EntityManager em = getManager();
        em.persist(t);
        em.flush();
        int id = t.getId();
        em.close();
        return id;
    }

}
```

The getting operations works just fine, and when I save the entity is getting an ID, and somehow saved into local context. But when I check my MySQL database, it says that the table is an empty set. No data is being saved to the database.

I've tried various things and tried adding flush() after persist, but with no luck.

Why can't I seem to get this working? Any ideas?

Comment: so you close the EntityManager before committing the transaction?

Comment: You're not committing your transaction. Also, EMF should be created once and only once. Creating it is a costly operation, that reads all the metadata, annotations, etc. You should also respect the Java naming conventions, use try-finally to make sure the em is always closed, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SaveTestfixture(Testfixture t)`

you want to not use `em.close();` but `Close();`

Also why is this method annotated with `@Transactional`

Comment: Yes! Of course, can't tell you how I missed that! Fantastic! :) 
It's annotated because I litterally tried everything. Even dropped a prayer.. 
Thank you Scary Wombat (Y) :D